# Module compiled with Swift 5.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1.3 compiler

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Check several publications with the same compilation error, and it really seems annoying that some libraries do not have support for current versions, well Apple also updates the Xcode many times along with the Swift version. Then after reviewing many publications and research, I discovered this [post](https://swift.org/blog/abi-stability-and-more/#module-stability) where they indicate:

> Swift 5 provides binary compatibility for applications: a guarantee
>   that, in the future, an application created with one version of the
>   Swift compiler will be able to communicate with a library built with
>   another version. This applies even when using the version
>   compatibility mode from previous languages ​​(-swift-version 4.2).

In other cases, they indicate using **carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries** but I am using cocoapod so I cannot use that solution and finally indicate enabling **Build Libraries For Distribution**, but nothing really worked for me until now and I can't help thinking that maybe tomorrow they will launch swift 5.1.4 and the support they make for swift 5.1.3 is unusable. 
I really hope you can help me with the solution to the problem I present with the compilation error and if anyone knows about the post **ABI STABILITY**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can simply build the module yourself. If the source for the module is not available, then you are at risk for this problem. It's one reason not to use such modules. See if your module is available as a Swift Package, then it will be rebuilt as needed, automatically.

Comment: Of course I understand you mean having the source code, unfortunately I don't have it. @johnelemans

Comment: The libraries imported must have 'Build Libraries For Distribution' set, not the app. Then those libs will export a text-based equivalent of .modulemap that the linker can use across Swift versions.

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment: the text-based equivalent to the .swiftmodule is .swiftinterface. see https://swift.org/blog/library-evolution/

Comment: @dbenitobaldeonon did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: nothing, only request a new version from the library and disable update in the mac @DhavalKansara